# Get attribute label by attribute code without load by product id

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, labels

Is it possible to get the attribute label (depending on the storeview) only by the attribute code?
I don't want to enter any product or product id.

This is my code to get the attribute label:

```
<?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_name); ?>
<?php $attribute_label = $_attribute->getStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName()); ?>
```

I want to get rid of the **$_product.**

Comment: Are talking about attribute Label or option label?

Comment: Attribute Label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using function [***`getStoreLabel()`***](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php) of class *`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute`*,You can get store Label of a store view

```
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','attrbute_code');
//print_r($attributeModel);
echo $attributeModel->getStoreLabel('Store_id');
```